# Error parsing JSON in swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

I am trying to parse JSON in swift 4, but I get the following error:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). The process has been left at the
>   point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to
>   the state before expression evaluation.

This is my code:

```
struct Beer : Codable {
    let name: String
    let brewery: String
    let style: String
}

let jsonResponse = [
    "name": "Endeavor",
    "brewery": "Saint Arnold",
    "style": "ipa"
]

let jsonString = String(describing: jsonResponse)

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) 

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let beer = try! decoder.decode(Beer.self, from: jsonData!)

print(beer)
```

Comment: Why do you think `String(describing: jsonResponse)` will create a JSON string?

Comment: If you use `try`/`catch` instead of `try!` you might get a more helpful error :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating JSON data correctly. `String(describing:)` does not create JSON strings. It creates a debug description of an object, which has *nothing* to do with JSON.

Rather than using a Dictionary it would be cleaner to create `Data` from a `Beer` object, then deserialize it again:

```
struct Beer : Codable {
    let name: String
    let brewery: String
    let style: String
}

//Create a Beer
let aBeer = Beer(name: "Endeavor", brewery: "Saint Arnold", style: "ipa") //Create a Beer object
//--------------------------------------
 //Serialize (dehydrate) the Beer
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let jsonData: Data
do {
 jsonData = try encoder.encode(aBeer)
} catch  {
   fatalError("Splat!. \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
//---------------------------------------
//print the dehydrated Beer

if let jsonText = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("JSON text = \(jsonText)")
}
//---------------------------------------
 //Deserialize (rehydrate) the Beer
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decodedBeer = try! decoder.decode(Beer.self, from: jsonData)

print("Rehydrated beer = \(decodedBeer)")
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to create your JSON data from a dictionary rather than from a `Beer` object?

Answer (score 0):

First create JSON data by encoding your response and then decode it.

```
struct Beer : Codable {
     let name: String
     let brewery: String
     let style: String
}

let jsonResponse = [
    "name": "Endeavor",
    "brewery": "Saint Arnold",
    "style": "ipa"
]

let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonResponse, 
options: .prettyPrinted)

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()

let encoded = try jsonEncoder.encode(jsonResponse)

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

let beer = try jsonDecoder.decode(Beer.self, from: data!)

print(beer)
```